# IE7 checkbox alignment issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm having a problem trying to align custom checkboxes correctly in IE7 - all other browsers I've checked look fine. IE7 specific CSS is already overriding inline-block with inline and setting zoom: 1, so I'm not sure how to get round this. The test page is at [snip]  - any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Put an conditional comment and let ie rest in peace

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 7<br />
<![endif]-->
```

[More info](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: I have this line `html.ie7 .ez-checkbox, html.ie7 .ez-radio { zoom: 1; display:inline; _height:31px; }`

Comment: try `margin-top:-31px`; and let me know

Comment: Thanks. I've added that now, but I can't check it as I'm back home on my linux box, how does it look to you?